# LaTeX display problem on iPad

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, math-display

I sometimes browse the site on an iPad (16GB no 3G) using Safari and have noticed that many of the LaTeX equations are not rendered properly on stats.SE but are on other sites including the MathJax website and others: [Example](http://www.leancrew.com/all-this/2010/07/how-many-samples/) (chosen because it uses \hat which doesn't display properly on stats.SE).

Here are a couple more examples:

$$\hat{x}_n$$

$$\hat{\rho}_j$$

$$\langle x, y \rangle$$

Can anybody reproduce this and is there any fix?
Is it due to a font choice on stats.SE?

**Edit**: I checked math.SE and it has the same issue. MathOverflow does not. I'll try to post screenshots later if that would help.

Comment: throw away your iPad and buy the next generation version! organize your i-life!

Comment: @shabbychef, are the new ones coming with a new browser with better font support? (I believe that may be part of the issue.) Mine has already mostly been co-opted from me anyway. Maybe you know of such things. Problem solved!

Comment: the Apple motto is "we don't cut corners: we add bevels!"

Comment: @shabbychef, nothing wrong with bevels. I'll take them over shards. Still boggles my mind which is the bigger of the two these days. Though I own a Mac, the iPad came my way for free. But, I'd still like it to play nicer with stats.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was intentional – there will be slight rendering issues with MathJax due to not wanting to take on the PNG dependency of the font renderings.  Adding the PNG folder would add 29,012 files, 317 folders and 114 MB of images to the project.

We are not sure it’s worth it really for these small edge cases.

Comment: @Geoff, I'll be honest. When I first saw this post, I literally thought it was a joke. I had to re-read it a couple times to see that your tongue *wasn't* planted firmly in cheek. While 29K files is borderline "large", 114 MB is not. I can't imagine that the "maintenance" requirements on this could be large (it's just a font repository). At any rate, I found the following (recent) thread, but it's a little vague so I'm not sure if it might be relevant or not: [MathJax: iOS4.2 and web fonts](http://groups.google.com/group/mathjax-dev/browse_thread/thread/89d162e8d530673)

Comment: @Cardinal - please read: http://www.mathjax.org/resources/faqs section:  The MathJax font folder is too big. Is there any way to compress it?

Comment: @Geoff, yeah, I know. I already read it. In case you couldn't tell, **my** tongue was ever-so-slightly planted in cheek. Is the link I posted in any way relevant? It looked like there might be a "new" (?) dev fork that handles iOS4.2 specifically. Yes? No?

Comment: @Geoff, and though I use mostly Mac products, I'm not rabid enough to take offense to your "small edge cases" remark. :)

Comment: @Cardinal we will be paying close attention to the developments of MathJax as it progresses through version 1.1:  http://www.mathjax.org/2011/01/14/news/mathjax-version-1-1-beta-ready-for-testing/ - as soon as we have our hands on an official 1.1 version we will install and revisit this.

Comment: @Geoff, fair enough. I'm sure the support of such a large, fairly complex site keeps you busy. Thanks for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 1):

I took a screenshot on my iPhone 4 to illustrate:

[image: iphone 4 math screenshot]

Does this render correctly, on, say, [math.stackexchange.com](http://math.stackexchange.com) ?

Comment: thanks! I've edited the question above to reflect some further experimentation.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Windows Internet Explorer 8.0 on a typical PC, and in "normal view" I get the first image below.  Under "compatibility view" I get the second image.   There may be Mathjax issues.

[image]

[image]